# Pandas CSV to new table column and rows

Tags: python, csv, pivot, pandas-groupby

I am trying to use column values of Type in the CSV table below as Rows of a new table.

## Old Table

| Fruits | Type |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | High |
| Orange | Medium |
| Grape | Low |
| Mango | High |
| Apple | Medium |
| Grape | Info |

I tried few options with pivot_table, groupby like below but couldn't get like the new table I would like to get.

df_tab= df.pivot_table(values=df[Type].value_counts(), index=df.set_index('Fruits'), columns='Type', aggfunc='sum')

## New Table:

| Fruit | High | Medium | Low | Info |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Orange | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Grape | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| Mango | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Answer (score 0):

You can create 3 empty lists and loop through the type column and fill these lists, then add them to the data frame.

```
Medium = []
High = []
Low = []
info = []
for row in df["Type"]:
    if row == "Medium":
         Medium.append(1)
         High.append(0)
         Info.append(0)
         Low.append(0)
    elif row == "High":
         Medium.append(0)
         High.append(1)
         Info.append(0)
         Low.append(0)
    elif row == "info":
         Medium.append(0)
         High.append(0)
         Info.append(1)
         Low.append(0)
    elif row == "Low":
         Medium.append(0)
         High.append(0)
         Info.append(0)
         Low.append(1)


df["Medium"] = Medium
df["High"] = High
df["Info"] = Info
df["Low"] = Low
```

Answer (score -1):

I used **groupby**

```
df_grp df.groupby(['Fruits', 'Type']).aggregate('size').unstack().fillna(0).reset_index()
```

output is

```
Type  Fruits  High  Info  Low  Medium
0      Apple   1.0   0.0  0.0     1.0
1      Grape   0.0   1.0  1.0     0.0
2      Mango   1.0   0.0  0.0     0.0
3     Orange   0.0   0.0  0.0     1.0
```

you can delete columns name (Type) like this if you want

```
df_grp.columns = list(df_grp.columns)
```

output is

```
   Fruits  High  Info  Low  Medium
0   Apple   1.0   0.0  0.0     1.0
1   Grape   0.0   1.0  1.0     0.0
2   Mango   1.0   0.0  0.0     0.0
3  Orange   0.0   0.0  0.0     1.0
```